# pydoc generated help-text with file handle parameters

Tags: python, pydoc

I have a function with the following parameter list:

```
def print(*line, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, default = 'full'):
```

Unfortunately the pydoc help text for the module shows it like this:

```
FUNCTIONS
print(*line, sep=' ', end='\n', file=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='cp850'>, default='full')
```

How can I make pydoc give the file argument as `file=sys.stdout` rather than showing the gory details of the object?

Python 3.2, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution:

```
def print(*line, sep=' ', end='\n', file=None, default = 'full'):
    '''If file is None, defaults to sys.stdout.'''

    if file is None:
        file = sys.stdout
```

(But please consider not using `print` and `file` as identifiers. `print` esp. will break Python 2-compatibility forever.)

Comment: That works, thanks. It does seem rather a pain to have to change one's code just to get readable help text. I looked in the pydoc module and found how it was getting information for functions, and I can't see a simple way around it (other than altering my code).  By the way the project is Python 3 only.  Thanks for the advice, but I'm not concerned about backward compatibility.  This is only a small part of the code, there's no way the rest will ever work on Py2 anyway.